# Calculating one way ANOVA

Tags: r, anova

I have stage specific affymetrix data of Plasmodium falciparum with columns as the stages (7) and the rows contain the row IDs (22769 gene IDs)

I have normalized the data using the `Affy` package, `method = rma` in `R`.

How to calculate p-value by one way ANOVA and filtering out the data with values having p-value <0.05?

I get the following error when I write the command: "cannot allocate vector size of 3.9gb"
I also tried in linux, but there to I get the error: "cannot allocate vector size of 27gb"

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: What functions/packages are you using to calculate your ANOVA? Also, what is the size of your dataset? (7x22769?) The error message is saying that the calculations used to get the result is creating a huge matrix whose dimensions exceed 3.9/27GBs.

Comment: can you give a *small* reproducible example (e.g. an analysis of a small subset of the gene IDs) to show what you're trying to do?

Comment: I am using limma package to calculate the p value.